# Single log in for multiple moodle installation

Tags: moodle

I have installed three instances of moodle in the local site for the three different courses for three diffirent languages

localhost/netstudy/english/

localhost/netstudy/marathi/

localhost/netstudy/hindi/

I want to have a single login page containing the dropdown for the selection course language. How to bypass the moodle login so that depending on the course language selection respective course moodle shoo

```html
<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="http://localhost/netstudy/english/login/index.php">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><strong>Member Login </strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="78">Username</td>
<td width="6">:</td>
<td width="294"><input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="mypassword" type="text" id="mypassword"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>
```

I am new to the moodle please help me out with this.

Comment: 3 installations is a bit of an overkill... You can specify the language for the course in the course settings. I would have a single instance with 3 categories, one for each language, with the course in each category

Comment: Those three courses are totally different and have the pratice test conducted in that so is it possible somehow to use single login page so that i can login to any of the three different moodles installed.  by using the above code i am able to bypass only single moodle installation because directly i have specified the action for single course . But how to do when i have drop down for language  selection to go to respective moodle.

Answer (score 1):

Well, Okay. First, you need to know that what you're building is a bit silly - 3 installation is very, very over-the-top. You can instead have a single site and  a single course with 3 language settings.

And if the content is different like you said in your comment above, you can still configure the course to have 3 different content catalogues using conditional access (All in the same installation).

Having 3 instances of Moodle running simultaneously will significantly impede any low/mid-range server.

---

Ranting aside, if you really want to do this, you can add a dropdown box in your login form which enables users to select the language/site they would like to log into. You can then [post](http://mrarrowhead.com/index.php?page=Php_passing_variables.php) this data onwards in a PHP script.

A bunch of if-statements should do the job.

Pseudo code:

```
HTML:
<input type="select" name="lingo"/><br/>
    <option value="1">English</option>
    <option value="2">Marathi</option>
    <option value="3">Hindi</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="username"/><br/>
<input type="text" name="password"/><br/>
<button to submit goes here>
```

```
PHP:
If lingo == 1{
    post username and passwords to English_login.php;
}
elseif lingo == 2{
    post username and passwords to Marathi_login.php;
}
else{
    post username and passwords to Hindi_login.php;
}
```

That should give you an idea of how to go about having a single login page, but I must reiterate that this is probably a bad idea.

Good luck with your project all the same. :)